# Выровнять по вертикали элемент в блоке javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Задачка типовая. Выровнять блок по вертикали по центру. Но только на чистом JS.

HTML

```
<div class="d_row">
    <div class="d_col_d_4 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text script-el">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="d_col_d_4 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text script-el">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="d_col_d_4 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text script-el">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d_row">
    <div class="d_col_d_4 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text script-el">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="d_col_d_8 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d_row">
    <div class="d_col_d_8 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text script-el">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="d_col_d_4 script-id">
        <h4 class="p_text script-el">Extreme Sports and Expeditions</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var scopeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('script-id');
var elementH4 = document.getElementsByClassName('script-el');
elementH4.style.marginTop = scopeDiv.offsetHeight/2 - elementH4.offsetHeight;
//  scopeDiv.offsetHeight;
```

Данный код не работает(
Помогите кто чем может.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов ( массивооподобный объект ), у него нет свойства `offsetHeight`, поэтому у вас не получается посчитать нужный отступ

Можете считать по первому элементу (у вас это `elementH4[0]` и `scopeDiv` соответственно ) у них уже есть нужные вам свойства

```
var scopeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('script-id');
var elementH4 = document.getElementsByClassName('script-el');
var marginTop = scopeDiv[0].offsetHeight/2 - elementH4[0].offsetHeight;
elementH4[0].style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
```

**P.S.** не забывайте добавлять меру *px* когда работаете со стилями

Можете использовать еще цилк

```
var scopeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('script-id');
var elementH4 = document.getElementsByClassName('script-el');
for(var i = 0; i < scopeDiv.length; i++) {
    var marginTop = scopeDiv[i].offsetHeight/2 - elementH4[i].offsetHeight;
    elementH4[i].style.marginTop = marginTop + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Но мне нужны все scopеDiv' ы, а не только первый...

Comment: ругаеться хроме на Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'marginTop' of undefined

Comment: @mangoloid1, обновил ответ